# Why socket doesn't close after reading what the user has entered once?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm using the followin code in the server of a chat application , where I'm using a seprate thread for each client . 
**Code:**

```
public void run()
{
String msg;
InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream())
BufferReader r= new BufferedReader(isReader);
int i=0,j=0;
System.out.print("entered run again"+i++);
try{
             while((msg=r.readLine())!=null)
    {
        System.out.println("readed"+msg );

            spreadMsg(msg);

    }


    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}


 }


}
```

why the while loop   **"while((msg=r.readLine())!=null)"** is beahaving as infinite loop and why it's not returning after it has read the only line I've entered.

Comment: I know I'm missing some concept please reply

Comment: why it should close? infinite loop is normal behaviour in your code.

Comment: I thought it should once it has read everything enetered at one time as in case of normal string reading . But now got the point it will return null only on closing the socket

Answer (score 0):

the stream returned by `Socket.getInputStream()` does not return null until the socket has been closed by the client.

Comment: The 'stream returned by `Socket.getInputStream()`' doesn't 'return null' at all. It either returns a non-null value or throws an exception. If you are referring to the `readLine()` method you need to say so explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

> why the while loop "while((msg=r.readLine())!=null)" is beahaving as infinite loop and why it's not returning after it has read the only line I've entered.

The other end didn't close the connection so the reader doesn't know you are only going to send one line.

If you want to assume only one line will be sent, you can close the connection yourself instead of having a loop.